# Lint don't override field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

I'm new in using Lint and I'm getting a blue underline on my `UserModel` variables with a message of `Don't override fields` and `Annotate overridden members`. I'm having a hard time understanding the Good and Bad rules in the example docs. I still get the same message after adding `@override`.

```
class UserModel extends UserEntity {
  final int id;
  final String? uid;
 
  const UserModel(
      {required this.id,
      this.uid})
      : super(
          id: id,
          uid: uid,
        );
}


//

class UserEntity extends Equatable {
  const UserEntity({
    required this.id,
    this.uid,
    this.provider,
   });

  final int id;
  final String? uid;
 
  static const empty = UserEntity(id: 0, uid: '');

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];
}
```

Comment: The [`overridden_fields` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/overridden_fields.html) is warning you that you're overriding a field.  Adding an `@override` attribute won't help.  If you don't want the warning, don't override the base fields, use a getter and/or setter in the derived class instead if possible, or use `// ignore: overridden_fields` to suppress the lint.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2428.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fields `id` and `uid` already are defined within the `UserEntity` class so it is redundant to declare them again as fields in the `UserModel` class.

```dart
class UserModel extends UserEntity {
  const UserModel({required int id, String? uid}) : super(id: id, uid: uid);
}
```

---

EDIT: as of [dart 2.17](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d) you can simplify the above code by using super initializers.

```dart
class UserModel extends UserEntity {
  const UserModel({required super.id, super.uid});
}
```